# Populate unordered list with list on external page with jquery/ajax?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I need a list where when a user types a letter into an above input, the list displays words starting with that letter.  Thus, if a user types in "a" into the input,  a dropdown ul pops out and displays words from an external php page starting with "a", maybe "apple" or "artifact".  Additionally, if the user types in "ab", the page should show all words starting with "ab".

I know I have to use Jquery ajax somehow to GET the data from the external page (which is just on a simple list) and insert specific data into the other page based upon the letters typed in by the user.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the callback from your ajax call, which is returning an array of words, something like this should work

```
function ajaxComplete(listOfWords){
    var ul = $("<ul />");
    for(var i = 0; i < listOfWords.length; i++)
        ul.append("<li>" + listOfWords[i] + "</li>");
    $("#someDiv").html(ul);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, if you can control your external page, is to modify it to return JSON data. You can then use jQuery UI Autocomplete out-of-the-box.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete

> When a String is used [as the data source parameter], the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP). The request parameter "term" gets added to that URL. The data itself can be in the same format as the local data described above.

If you cannot modify the page, you must use the third type of jQuery UI Autocomplete, which is to pass a callback to the plugin. Then, write a callback function that `.get()`s the data off your other page and parses it. This is easy with jQuery's DOM traversal methods.